# Why is it true that $T^2 = S^1 \times S^1$

Tags: general-topology

This might be an elementary question but why is it true that $T^2 = S^1 \times S^1$? My book simply defines

$$T^n = S^1 \times \cdots \times S^1 (n\text { times})$$

But I can't picture why this definition makes sense? Or maybe it's not something that I should picture in my head (in $T^2$ case)?

Comment: It would be highly wise to define your symbols: most people surely will know what $\;S^1\;$ is, but those $\;T\,'$ s are harder to guess...Perhaps you mean toruses?

Comment: Intuition: What is a torus? It is a ring of rings. Slice it and the cross section is (two) circles. As you rotate your slices, you get circles that eventually loop back together on themselves like points on a circle.

Comment: Do you have any trouble to visualize $\mathbb{S}^1\times [0,1]?$ Is not $\mathbb{S}^1=[0,1]/{0\backsim 1}?$

Comment: @Bye_World Meaning that if you tell me $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ is a square then I have no problem visualizing that, but in this case I have problem visualizing that

Comment: @mfl What is $[0,1]/0$?

Comment: It means that if you identify $0$ with $1$ in $[0,1]$ then you get $\mathbb{S}^1.$ So, if you identify the two ends of a cylinder you get a torus.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are asking. Do you have some other conception of the torus that you are having trouble comparing this definition with? If so, what is that other conception, and what is the trouble that you are having? If not, do you simply not understand the notation of the definition? Is this the first time you've ever heard of the torus, and you are just asking for some intuition of this definition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is that the points on $T^2$ can be parametrized by $(x,y)$ where each of $x,y$ are in the circle. If you consider the picture below we see a grid on the torus that makes a coordinate system in this way.

[image]